# Generating a Range of Ascii Values

Tags: javascript

Is there a more effective way of generating ascii values? I'm trying to emulate this same pattern in JavaScript that I've written in Bash.

**Bash**

```
read -ra chars <<< $(echo -e "$(printf '\\x%x ' {33..126})")
```

**JS**

```
var chars = [];
for(var chr = 33; chr < 126; chr++) {
  chars.push(String.fromCharCode(chr));
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with them?  Do you want to just print them out or do you want to use them to validate input or something else?

Comment: I just need them in an array so I can can use them to create a password. @madamission

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to generate a password from them, you might as well just put all the characters in a string, something like this: [Generate random string/characters in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-a-string-of-5-random-characters-in-javascript)

Comment: I'll check out the link. The whole point of generating the array was to have all of the characters and then shuffling them and finally calling join to return a string.